# How to set horizontal scroll position react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to make a page set it's horizontal scrolling position in the middle on load.

I've tried calling window.scrollBy (and the others like scrollTo etc) in the componentDidMount function (which I confirmed is being called).
I can't get it to work for horizontal nor vertical scrolling.
The npm package 'react-scroll' did work but only for vertical scrolling.

EDIT:
tech_amity is right that these functions take two arguments: the x and y coordinate.
In my case however the problem was solved by accessing the window.scrollTo() function from the onLoad event on a new parent container div. I'm still not really sure why.

so:

```
function moveLeft()
{
  window.scrollTo(300, 0);
}

//and then in the JSX/html:

<div onLoad={moveLeft}>
//... stuff i want to scroll
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give proper co-ordinates in scroll function.

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
window.scrollTo(scroll-to-middle, 0);
```

give x-co-ordinates according to you.